# Enable Schedule Trigger for Azure Data factory through poweshell script in CICD pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory, cicd

I am enabling schedule trigger in data factory through powershell script in release pipeline of Azure DevOps.

I have written script as below:
Install-PackageProvider nuget -force
Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 -Force -AllowClobber

$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "abc" -DataFactoryName "fgh" -Name $_.name -Force }

I am getting this error.

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
PowerShell exited with code '1'.

what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be complicating things with nuget packages and such.

Here is the simple Powershell Script that I use for PostDeploy to specify which triggers to enable:

```
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $globalParametersFilePath,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $resourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $dataFactoryName
)

$triggersADF = @(
    
    'Trig_CMSFileDeployment_Prod',
    'Trig_StorageEvent_stccokops_blob-cmsfiledeploy-configfiles',
    'Trig_CMSFileDeployment_Prod'
    )
}

$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName -Name $_ -Force }
```

Here is what I have as my script arguments as well:

```
-resourceGroupName "rg-ccok-ops-$(Environment)-001"
-dataFactoryName "adf-ccok-opscmsfiledeploy-$(Environment)-001"
```

Here is a screenshot of the Az Powershell task in my release Pipeline (There is one additional script arg you don't need as I had to modify some things for this example)

[image: Release Pipeline Powershell task]

If you want to just enable all triggers that are in your ADF you can use this code (rather than individually specifying each trigger):

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string]$ResourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string]$dataFactoryName,
)

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($(Get-AzureRmContext).Account)) {
    Add-AzureRmAccount
}

$ADF_Triggers = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host $ADF_Triggers.Name
if ($notPresent) {
    Write-Host "Trigger does not exist. Nothing to enable!"
}
else {
    $ADF_Triggers | ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "Enabling Pipeline Trigger $($_.name)"
        Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName -Name $_.name -Force 
    }
}
```

Kudos to https://bzzzt.io/post/2018-11/2018-11-08-adf/ for part of this code